# Quicksort code keeps giving me StackOverflowError

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I've written this code for a quicksort but I'm getting StackOverflowError and I can't find the reason why. I've tried to make sure that the recursion has the right pivot, front and back values which is where I think is messing up but at this point I'm not too sure.

```
   {
       int intTemp = 0;
       int intPivotP = intPivot;
       int intFrontP = intFront;
       int intBackP = intBack;
       //System.out.println ("front");
       while (intFront != intBack - 1 && intFront < intBack)
       {
           //System.out.println ("while");
           if (aClone [intFront] <= aClone [intPivot] && aClone [intBack] >= aClone [intPivot])
           {
               intFront = intFront + 1;
               intBack = intBack - 1;
           }

           else if (aClone [intFront] > aClone [intPivot] && aClone [intBack] >= aClone [intPivot])
           {
               intBack = intBack - 1;
           }

           else if (aClone [intFront] <= aClone [intPivot] && aClone [intBack] < aClone [intPivot])
           {
               intFront = intFront + 1;
           }

           else if (aClone [intFront] > aClone [intPivot] && aClone [intBack] < aClone [intPivot])
           {
               intTemp = aClone [intBack];
               aClone [intBack] = aClone [intFront];
               aClone [intFront] = intTemp;
           }
       }

       if (intFrontP < intBackP)
       {
           //quick ((intBackP - intFrontP) / 2 + intFrontP, intFrontP, intPivotP - 1);
           quick ((intPivotP - intFrontP) / 2 + intFrontP, intFrontP, intPivotP - 1);
           quick ((intBackP - intPivotP) / 2 + intPivotP, intPivotP, intBackP);
       }
   }
```

For clarification, `aClone` is an array of integers.

Comment: It looks like quicksort.  But if you want to know if it is a correct implementation .... **test it**.

Comment: @StephenC hm, difficult to test, how would you tell it from a merge sort, both are sorting...

Comment: Actually, deleting a downvoted question *does not* repair the down-votes from the perspective of Question blocks.  (That would be just too easy.  Ask a bad question, delete it, repeat *ad nauseum*.  The Question blocks are designed so that you can't do that kind of thing.)  The best that deleting will do is to stop more down-votes.

Comment: If you care about your reputation, and/or don't want to get Question blocked, the best strategy is to not ask bad questions.  It is not that hard to do.  You just need to read, understand and follow the guidelines.

Comment: It appears the example code will not work. One key issue is that the input parameters are modified, when they need to be reused as parameters on recursive calls. The pivot needs to be the value and not the index, since swapping may move the pivot. The compares are normally < instead of <= and > instead of >=. The code appears to be an attempt at Hoare partition scheme. The wiki article for quick sort includes [example pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). Rewrite your code based on the Wiki pseudo code.

Comment: Continuing, not explained in the Wiki example pseudo code is the two do ... while loops rely on encountering the pivot or an element equal to the pivot to stop the loops if they don't encounter an out of place element. The code may end up swapping the pivot and/or elements equal to the pivot, but it's not an issue, The partitioning splits a sub-array into two parts, elements <= pivot, elements >= pivot, and the pivot or elements equal to the pivot can end up anywhere during a partition step and may not be put in place until the base case of a sub-array of size 1.

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks man that really helped. I was just testing it and it gave me StackOverflowError so that might be why

Comment: @curiosa Well I don't mind that that much, maybe I will later but it's just like a genuine question that I have so I won't delete it. I've just started to learn about sorting so yeah I'm very confused about it sometimes.

Comment: @curiosa  Well well well who would've thought. I'm still trying to fix the code. As suggested by rcgldr , it might be because that intBack, intFront will change and that intPivot might change so that might be why is causing me StackOverflowError. I don't think I can put the 2 recursive calls up at the top but if I make 3 more variables to store their values that would take up way more memory right? How can I solve that?

Comment: @curiosa Well I made some changes so I might just ask another question since I know I'm getting stack overflow error now. But I might still be banned from asking questions ‍♂️

Comment: @curiosa Since my questions got downvoted before and I asked 2 of those type of questions in 1 day. the site banned me from asking questions for 3 days.

Comment: @curiosa well I figured that since it's probably a problem with the recursing part. I made another overloaded quick  so it can actually end it self

Comment: @curiosa and what do you mean by resilient?? I sometimes wanna end my self with these code lol

Comment: @N0ob - taking up a bit more memory for local variables shouldn't be a concern. In my prior comments, I was suggesting that it would probably be better to start with the wiki pseudo code example rather than trying to fix the code in the question, since fixing all of the problems will end up with code that will be very similar to the psuedo code in the wiki article.

Comment: @N0ob *end myself* yes, this index stuff is error prone and hard. And it looks like you're lost and left guessing now, applying random changes. You always worry about performance, but an optimized version is a tough piece of code. The [functional version](https://gist.github.com/eloipereira/9ad98522ec5b49bcf04242e1ef9221a0) is much easier to understand, and logically equal. But when you have that, you're sure, you know quicksort. From there you could approach optimized versions. After staring at your code for a while, I'm not sure, if its quicksort really, perhaps just looks similar from afar.